# Java BlockingQueue Messages Lagging issue between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, blockingqueue

I have implemented a two player game with thread pool of sockets. each player connects to their own thread. I added a message Queue system according to [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1339471&seqNum=4) article.

Problem is the messages are lagging. the first respond from the first player is added to messageQueue as expected. But second player doesn't received it by calling `poll()` it only receives null yet.
And then the second player responds the second player receives the first players message. My intention is to send the message to second player before his/her response.

I must be doing some mistake or I have neglected some important concept.

Can you please help me find it?

My Code goes like this, there are two Classes related to this, GameRunnable.java and Game.java. I have omitted some code to simplify this mess.

In GameRunnable class ;

```
public static final Map<GamerRunnable, BlockingQueue<String>> messageQueues = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
public static final Map<String, GamerRunnable> gameQueue = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private Game game;


public void run() {
    System.out.println
        (this.setGameInstance(clientSocket, readerIn, output) ? "OK": "FAILED");
    messageQueues.put(this, new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(100));

    // If player 1
    this.game.initGame(this);

    // If Player 2
    this.game.initGame(this);
}

public static GamerRunnable getGameThreadByName(String name) {
    return gameQueue.get(name);
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

in Game.java

```
public Game(Socket clientSocket, BufferedReader readIn, OutputStream output) {
    this.sockGamer = clientSocket;

    try {
        this.out = output;
        this.inGamer = readIn; 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    public void sendToGamer(String msg) {
        try {
            this.out.write((msg+"\n").getBytes());
            this.out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void initGame(GamerRunnable game) {
    try {
        boolean messageLoop = true;

        String line1 = null;
        String line2 = null;

        while (messageLoop) {

            line1 = inGamer.readLine();

            if (line1 != null) {

                System.out.println("Gamer says: "+line1);

                GamerRunnable gamer2 = null;
                if (game.getName().equals("red")) {
                    gamer2 = GamerRunnable.getGameThreadByName("black");
                }
                else if (game.getName().equals("black")) {
                    gamer2 = GamerRunnable.getGameThreadByName("red");
                }

                if (gamer2 != null) {                       
                    System.out.println("Adding to Queue");
                    GamerRunnable.messageQueues.get(gamer2).offer(line1);
                }
            }

            line2 = GamerRunnable.messageQueues.get(game).poll();

            if (line2 != null) {
                //receiving from Queue
                System.out.println(line2);
                game.getGameInstance().sendToGamer(line2);      
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to network latency you may need a short delay to wait for the first message to arrive on the queue. Try [poll(time, unit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) instead. This will wait for the specified time for a message to appear on the queue. If nothing is there it will return a null like poll() is now. A user will probably not notice a 500ms to 1s delay if no message is available.